# Hibernate makes problems on " nullable = false" in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to insert some of the values in MySQL table with hibernate . I am using following table :

```
create table test_settings (
  id bigint not null,
  address varchar(64),
  enabled smallint not null,
  max_count integer,
  storage_period integer,
  rocommunity varchar(128) not null,
  skip_unknown smallint not null,
  storage_type integer not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

and in java file i am trying to add values :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_settings ")
public class TestSettings extends Singleton {
@Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 64)
    String address;

    @Column(name = "storage_type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    StorageType storageType = StorageType.MEMORY;

    @Column(name = "max_count")
    Integer maxCountInMemory;

    @Column(name = "storage_period")
    Integer storagePeriod;

    @Column(name = "skip_unknown", nullable = false)
    boolean skipUnknown = true;

    @Column(name = "rocommunity", length = 128, nullable = false)
    String rocommunity = "public";

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    boolean enabled = false;
}
```

I can see my table in MySQL server :

```
mysql> describe test_settings;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| address             | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| enabled             | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_count           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rocommunity         | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| skip_unknown        | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| storage_period      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| storage_type        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But i am getting some exception problem while deploying . These are the complete stack trace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into mam_db.snmp_settings (address, enabled, max_count_in_memory, rocommunity, skip_unknown, storage_period, storage_type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null];


10:37:41,165 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116) Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'address' cannot be null
10:37:41,165 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
10:37:41,165 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
10:37:41,165 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:1077)
10:37:41,166 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
10:37:41,166 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
10:37:41,166 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 116)  ... 58 more
```

But i am using  *`nullable = false`* in java code . But this is working fine with `PostgreSQL` and `DB2` . Getting exception on MySQL only .

This is the corresponding `DB2` table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SETTINGS (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(64),
  ENABLED SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  MAX_COUNT INTEGER,
  STORAGE_PERIOD INTEGER,
  ROCOMMUNITY VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  SKIP_UNKNOWN SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  STORAGE_TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)#
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: The tables don't match. In DB2 the `address` column is `nullable` whereas not in MySQL. So you are using different create statements for the table (or the table already existed). So in short your table definitions on MySQL are different then in DB2.

Comment: Did you try setting the default values in the db as well?

Comment: The problem i am facing is that the 'address' column is getting update to not-null . After deploying the EAR file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Column(nullable = false)` is the JPA way to declare a column to be not-null. If you want that it will be able to insert `null` address do not use this annotation.